# Vue.js - httpVueLoader doesn't load a module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use `httpVueLoader` to be able to use [`vue-google-autocomplete`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete) but I'm stuck.

I have a `create.js` file and `create.html`

**create.html**

```
<vue-google-autocomplete classname="form-control" id="maps_autocomplete" placeholder="Start typing">
</vue-google-autocomplete>


// end of body

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&language=sk&region=SR"
        async defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static "realestates/create.js" %}">
```

But nothing is rendered, no error is raised and there is an empty `json` when I do:

```
Vue.options.components
{}
```

in console.

Do you know what to do? I'm new to this.